# Powershell pinned shortcut customisation

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, windows-domain

When right-clicking on the pinned Powershell item on my taskbar, it  pop up with tasks.
such as run as administrator.

Is there a way to add run as accounts to this, looking to add the domain administrator accounts so it will then pop up and ask for the password to be entered.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to add specific accounts, but I just SHIFT-Right Click then select "Run As Different User"

Answer (score 1):

If you hold down [Shift] and then right-click on the pinned taskbar icon, you are presented with a more classic right-click menu, which includes a "Run as different user" option.  As stated already, but note, this only works for me if PowerShell in not already running. It has to just be the pinned icon, not an active window.

Comment: If you pin it to the start menu instead of the task bar then you can shift right click even if powershell is running.

Comment: Its the shift click that I do at the moment, was looking to bypass the need to do this with a shorcut,